# QGIS merge vector layers and add a group field

Tags: qgis

Is there any way to merge several vector layers into a single layer while adding an attribute column that groups the points by the layers they belonged to prior?

So I have multiple delimited txt files with coordinates loaded into my project. I have figured out a couple of ways to merge them into a single shapefile but a group # or name would make it a lot quicker for me to use Points2One to create line data from my many sets of points.

[image]